# Iterator arithmetic

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm working right now with `iterators` **arithmetic operations** and stack on small problem .
I need to make a **Sum** of **first and last** element of `vector<int>` followed by **second and last** element of `vector<int>` , **third and last** element of `vector<int>`
Example:
**Input numbers by user**
`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
**Output should be**
`10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17`
**In general the code should do addition like that**
`1+9 2+9 3+9 4+9 5+9 6+9 7+9 ......`

So basically i need the actual code  for this arithmetic operation using `iterator` with member functions `*.begin() , *.end()` **only**  ! I've try many ways but nothing coming in my head how to do this operation only with `.begin()` and `.end()` . I found other member functions but this functions is explained in STD library, not in basic knowledge level. So i need help to make code  with only `begin()` and `end()` member functions if possible.

**Code i got so far**

```
int main()
{  

vector<int> numset;
int num_input;
auto beg=numset.begin(), end=numset.end();
while (cin>>num_input)
{
    numset.push_back(num_input);
}
for (auto it = numset.begin()+1; it !=numset.end(); ++it)
{
    // *it=*it+1+nuset.end(); -- Wrong  X
            // *it+=(end-beg)/2;      -- Totally wrong(and totally stupid) X
            // *it + numset.back()   -- can't use other member functions X 
    //////// I've stack here dont know what code need //////

              cout<<*it<<endl;    
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: C++ Primer by whom? Many books have similar titles.

Comment: Right now, you're adding the current element with its immediate predecessor rather than with the last element.

Comment: @AlexGreat: So how do you get the value of the last element?

Comment: Instead of `back()`, use `end()[-1]`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt : Works thanks ! But is there way using only `iterators` not including `subscript`

Comment: @Alex: Yes: `auto last = numset.end(); --last;` and use `*last`

Answer (score 0):

The operation you perform is `*it+*(it-1)`. (It might help to add more parentheses and spaces in your code.) That adds two adjacent elements from the sequence.

The last element in the sequence is `numset.back()`. So try `*it + numset.back()` instead. And there's no need to start with the second element, since you do want to print the sum of the first and last elements. If you don't want to print the sum of the last element with itself, you should stop at `end() - 1`, though.

Comment: Result is totally not the one i want ! its not give me a sum of all elements